# Does Fenugreek help in breast enlargement?

Tags: medical-science, breast, breast-enlargement

http://health.india.com/diseases-conditions/15-health-benefits-of-methi/

> **Breast Enlargement**
>   Want to enlarge your breasts? Include fenugreek in your regular diet. The oestrogen-like property of fenugreek can help in breast enlargement by balancing hormones in women.

http://www.homeremediesweb.com/fenugreek_health_benefits.php

> **Breast Enlargement**
>   Fenugreek is often used in many teas and other products that help balance women's hormones and/or enlarge the breasts. Therefore, a simple home remedy for breast enlargement is to make Fenugreek a part of your regular diet. A common suggestion is to consume up to 3g of Fenugreek per day

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does Fenugreek increase breastmilk?](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/17648/does-fenugreek-increase-breastmilk)

Comment: @ChrisW What has breast enlargement to do with the milk supply? This is about enlargement not about engorgement.

Comment: In nearby Bangladesh, prostitutes take [Oradexon](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/10173115) to make their breasts and general anatomy larger.

Answer (score 2):

The search query "breast & fenugreek" return a single paper on PubMed. It is published in *Obstetrics & Gynecology* and produced by the Department of Health Care Sciences, George Washington University School of Medicine. Its conclusions are as follows:

> "Bust enhancing" herbal products are widely advertised. No clinical trials have been published. These products contain a variety of ingredients, including grains, hops, saw palmetto, dong quai, chaste-tree berry, wild yam, kava, fennel, black cohosh, and fenugreek. Several of these herbs are hormonally active; for example, hops contain 8-prenylnaringenin, a phytoestrogen that is more potent than other dietary phytoestrogens. Many bust-enhancing dietary supplements contain substrates for Fusarium, a fungus that produces zearalenone, a potent estrogen that has been associated with breast enlargement in humans and other species. **The use of bust-enhancing products should be discouraged because of lack of evidence for efficacy and long-term safety concerns.**<sup>1</sup>

Please note that this answer does not constitute medical advice. It is only meant to summarize published research related to the topic and limited the cited sources. Consult your physician about what these results may mean for your health.

1. *Obstet Gynecol.* 2003 Jun;101(6):1345-9.
   "Bust enhancing" herbal products.
   Fugh-Berman A. Department of Health Care Sciences, George Washington University School of Medicine, Washington, DC, USA. fughberman@aol.com